# HTML5-how to open more than one cameras

Tags: html, camera

I have successful get the video streaming of local camera by use `getUserMedia()` in HTML5.But only one camera.I have two cameras,how to get their video streaming at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this does not appear to be possible, yet. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140221/accessing-two-different-web-camera-in-html5-and-jquery) and the comments below this article [here](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera). Basically the user decides via their browser settings which camera is primary, and no option for secondary, etc, camera exists as of yet.